# Initialization of a data member of union type

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, casting

Compiling the following code using C++11:

```
class CoolData {
public:
    typedef union {
        char char_t;
        int  int_t;
    } event_data_t;     

    CoolData() : _event_data(static_cast<event_data_t>(0)) {}

private:
    event_data_t _event_data;
};


int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
prog.cpp: In constructor 'CoolData::CoolData()': prog.cpp:8:54: error: no matching function for call to 'CoolData::event_data_t::event_data_t(int)'
CoolData() : _event_data(static_cast<event_data_t>(0)) {}
                                                      ^
prog.cpp:6:4: note: candidate: CoolData::event_data_t::event_data_t()   } event_data_t;  
                                                                   ^
prog.cpp:6:4: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided 
prog.cpp:6:4: note: candidate: constexpr CoolData::event_data_t::event_data_t(const CoolData::event_data_t&)
prog.cpp:6:4: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const CoolData::event_data_t&'
prog.cpp:6:4: note: candidate: constexpr CoolData::event_data_t::event_data_t(CoolData::event_data_t&&)
prog.cpp:6:4: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'CoolData::event_data_t&&'
```

I'd just like to initialize `_event_data` with an integer initial value, in the initializer list.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several alternatives you can choose from.
You can do either this:

```
CoolData() { _event_data.int_t = 0; }
```

Or this:

```
class CoolData {
public:
    using event_data_t = union U {
        U() { int_t = 0; }
        char char_t;
        int  int_t;
    };

    CoolData() { }

private:
    event_data_t _event_data;
};
```

Or even this:

```
class CoolData {
public:
    using event_data_t = union U {
        U(int v) { int_t = v; }
        char char_t;
        int  int_t;
    };

    CoolData(): _event_data{0} { }

private:
    event_data_t _event_data;
};
```

I suspect the last one is the one you are looking for.